# Designing of a RESTful API endpoint filter and search

Tags: api, rest, loopbackjs

I am in the process of developing some custom API endpoints (using loopback.io), on top of its existing CRUD endpoints.

In the past I've used some other Node RESTful API frameworks for prototyping, and really enjoyed the powerful filtering features they provide out of the box.

What I'd like to do is provide a similar set (or subset) of some kind of filtering for a custom endpoint. The endpoint just does a SQL query (with some JOINs) and returns an array of objects.

Is there any kind of standardized approach that I should use to design some filtering? For example, I may want to filter on fields of the base table, or filter on relations. I like the way loopback.io and sequelize allow relatively easy specification of `includes` to link related objects, as well as their filtering syntax.

How is this type of problem usually approached when a custom implementation is done?

Answer (score 0):

As you probably noticed with CRUD endpoints, LoopBack provides [querying](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Querying+data) out of the box via [filter](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Querying+data#Queryingdata-Filters) parameter. You can nicely experiment with it in [API Explorer](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Use+API+Explorer). If you want to expose querying for a custom [remote method](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+methods), just add filter as a parameter too.

*example-model.js*

```
module.exports = ExampleModel => {
  const search = async (filter = {}) => {
    return await ExampleModel.find(filter)
  }

  ExampleModel.remoteMethod('search', {
    description: 'Returns a set of ExampleModel based on provided query.',
    accepts: [
      {arg: 'filter', type: 'object', required: false}
    ],
    http: {path: '/search', verb: 'get'},
    returns: {root: true}
  })

  ExampleModel.search = search
}
```

Comment: The thing is, the filter will only work on loopback models. For some more advanced queries, I have found that the only way to do these is to write some custom SQL. However, it would be great to have some form of filtering (basic where, order, limit, offset) so that the endpoint is similar to the CRUD endpoints.